# WP simple pages are all 404

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I create a "page" in WP, a link automatically gets added to the top navigation and all pages are 404. At the moment this is a simple test site, using the standard  theme and relevant plugins: `qtranslate` and `advanced custom fields`. I have some custom templates but for "posts" and not "pages".

EDIT: If i reset the permalink structure to the default `/?p=123`, then my url is `domain.com?page_id=15&lang=en` and this is still 404

EDIT2: .htaccess content

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

How would one start debugging this?

Comment: Check your .htaccess file? Is the 404 page the wordpress 404 page or the web server 404?

Comment: Does it work if you disable the `qtranslate` plugin?

Comment: Nope, that even kills the 404 :) Just part of the header html loads.

Comment: Is debug set to true? It's false by default, find it in wp-config.php.

Answer (score 2):

1. First Try to set the permalink settings to the default value (www.yoursite.com/?id=123).
2. Now try to change it back something else.
3. If you still get 404 pages, choose the default permalinks option again, delete your .htaccess file (make sure you **back it up first** and have a copy!!!) and try option 2 again.

If it still does not work, and you are using a new server setup, the server might actually ignore your .htaccess file.
You can check it by locating your httpd.conf file on the apache server, and find if there is a line:
`AllowOverride None`
If the context of this line is specific for your wordpress public directory, you can change it to `AllowOverride All`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210820/apache-server-ignores-htaccess) answer for some more info.